# Additional closing reasons

Tags: discussion, closing, moderation

Can you think of additional closing reasons specific to this site?

Answer (score 1):

I believe we have enough with the current ones, **off-topic** is generally used to cover all other cases not covered by the specific ones.

Answer (score 0):

I had one in mind -- questions that are only specific to pirated copies of games. For example "Why am I missing the music in [game]?" However, I guess those could get closed for being off-topic.

Sort of.

Comment: That should be closed as off-topic

Comment: If so @Juan, than I would like to know where those kind of questions DO belong, as they aren't welcome on Super User either

Comment: Possibly the "too localized" reason covers this

Comment: @Ivo, he's talking about pirated games, so they don't belong on any SE site; perhaps an underground/not official forum?